# How to tell which JList among two has cursor focus in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, jlist, jcomponent

[image: Snippet]

Hi, I'm building a simple tagging tool using Java Swing. There are two JLists in the component, and whenever I click the tagging button, I want to add a tag to the given text. If my cursor focus is on the left JList, I want to modify the text on the left JList, and if it's on the right one, modify the right one. What I mean by cursor focus is the place where I can navigate the list items using keyboard arrows.

So the button listener should tell whether the current cursor focus is on the left Jlist or the right one. How should I do this? I've already tried using "getFocusOwner", but it returns the button I just clicked.

Comment: Your problem is that `What I mean by cursor focus...` is not "what the JVM means by cursor focus". :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not the most elegant way, you can add a `FocusListener` to your `Jlist`s

```
public class CheckFocus extends JFrame {

    JList<String> focusedList = null;
    JList<String> list1 = new JList<>(new String[]{"A", "B"});
    JList<String> list2 = new JList<>(new String[]{"1", "2"});

    CheckFocus() {

        JButton btn = new JButton("Who has focus?");

        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {    

                if (focusedList.equals(list1))
                    System.out.println("list1");
                else if (focusedList.equals(list2))
                    System.out.println("list2");
                else
                    System.out.println("none");
            }
        });

        MyFocusListener mfl = new MyFocusListener();
        list1.addFocusListener(mfl);
        list2.addFocusListener(mfl);

        getContentPane().add(list1, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        getContentPane().add(list2, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
        getContentPane().add(btn, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new CheckFocus();
    }


    class MyFocusListener extends FocusAdapter {

        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {

            super.focusGained(e);
            focusedList = (JList<String>) e.getSource();
        }
    }
}
```

If you select a cell on each list and then press a button, the JVM treats the lists the same - they both do not have focus *at the moment*. What you want is to know which had focus *just before* you pressed the button, but the JVM does not store this kind of information so you have to store it yourself.